# Abstract methods not-implemented error is not being thrown

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

So i was just trying to learn java coming from a C++ background, as part of a quick ramup I just implemented a base class from a abstract class as below

```
abstract class my_abstract_class
{
    abstract void my_abstract_function();
}

class my_concrete_class extends my_abstract_class
{

}

public class ConcreteClasses {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        my_concrete_class my_concrete_class = new my_concrete_class();

    }
```

This passes even though my concrete class is not implementing the abstract method nor is it a abstract class. Shouldn't a compilation error be thrown? Or am i missing something very basic here

PS: The error is shown by eclipse as part of the static analysis but I still wonder how this program compiles and runs without any issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Eclipse compiler is a bit special. If the code doesn't compile, it generates error messages, but still compiles the classes by generating dummy methods throwing exceptions.

If you run a project which has compilation errors, it warns you that you shouldn't do that, but you can still proceed.

Just don't do that, and don't ignore error messages from the compiler.

Comment: If you run your code outside Eclipse using javac from the command line you will get the compile error.

Comment: @Ending, Interesting! Its a little odd that you can just ignore the error from eclipse and run the program. Shouldn't the binary not be produced on compilation errors?

Comment: It can be useful when, in some big code base, there is a compilation error on some class and you want, for example, just to execute a unit test on some unrelated class.

Comment: Ahh, sounds like a risky use case, because i am pretty sure the program would crash if it was deployed in that state by mistake and we tried to call the abstract method. But i get the point. Thanks